# How can it be access violation when setting PAGE_READONLY(use VirtualprotectEx() )?

Tags: c

If I have a function foo() and I want to use VirtualProtectEx() to change the property
of a variable which is in the function foo().

Like this
VirtualProtectEx( GetCurrentProcess(), p, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_READONLY, &old);

When I set "PAGE_READONLY" and compile it, the massage will show access violation.

If I set "PAGE_READWRITE", it will execute successfully.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `p` is stored in the stack. By calling `VirtualProtectEx`, it will affect the whole page, not just `p` (Each memory page is smallest entity that cannot be fragmented any further). Therefore, if you try to change the permission for just `p`, it will change the permission of the entire page(entire stack in your case). And if you make the stack read-only, it would not be possible to execute your program anymore and will cause you to have memory access violation exception. So, in order to solve this problem consider allocating `p` in heap and freeing them when you are done with it.

Comment: char a[10];
void *p = &a;
a is a variable in the function and p is a pointer that point to
the address of a.
So I want to ask if I want to change the property of variable a,
how can I set it READONLY and wont be access violation or I cant change it because it will affect whole page not just variable a
thanks

Comment: Yes and `a` is still allocated in the stack, not in the heap. **For any reason** if you make the stack read-only, your program cannot continue to execute. Therefore, allocate this in the heap. use `char *p = (char *)malloc( sizeof(char[10]) )`

Comment: I have another question,
If I set PAGE_EXECUTE_READ
The program cannot continue to execute?